# Can we update Android app to Flutter app on Play Store

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have build an android app with java and published it to play store but now I want to rebuild it with Flutter and update it on play store can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as long as the package name stays the same (app identifier) and you can still sign your apk or app bundle with your private key / keystore